# To show the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition for limits holds.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Check if the following limit exists, if so show that the $\epsilon$ $\delta$ definition for limits holds.
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} \frac{(x-1)^2(y-2)^2}{x^2+y^2-2xy-4y+5}$$

**My answer:** So clearly the limit is zero, you can write $\frac{(x-1)^2(y-2)^2}{x^2+y^2-2xy-4y+5}$ as $\frac{(x-1)^2(y-2)^2}{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(1+2x-2xy)}$ and $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} \frac{1}{(y-2)^2}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{(1+2x-2xy)}{(x-1)^2(y-2)^2}=0$.

I am having difficulty showing the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition holds. The trouble I am having is bounding the denominator in $\frac{(x-1)^2(y-2)^2}{x^2+y^2-2xy-4y+5}$, the numerator can be handled quite easily.

Comment: Your factorisation is wrong

$$(x-1)^{2} + (y-2)^{2} + 1 + 2x - 2xy = x^{2} + y^{2} - 2xy - 4y + 6$$

and

$$\frac{ (x-1)^{2} (y-2)^{2} }{ (x-1)^{2} + (y-2)^{2} + (1+2x-2xy)} \ne \frac{1}{(y-2)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}} + \frac{1+2x-2xy}{(x-1)^{2}(y-2)^{2}}$$

Comment: Any response to my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note we can factorize the denominator $D$ as

$x^2+y^2-2xy-4y+5=(x-\frac{y}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}(y-2)^2-(y-2)-xy$

If $(x,y)$ closed to $(1,2)$, we know $(x-\frac{y}{2})^2,\frac{3}{4}(y-2)^2,(y-2)$ are very closed to $0$ and $-xy$ is closed to $-2$, hence we know the denominator $D$ satisfies

$$|D|\ge |xy|-|(x-\frac{y}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}(y-2)^2-(y-2)|\ge 1,$$
when $(x,y)$ closed to $(1,2)$.

Then combine with numerator, which is closed to $0$ when $(x,y)$ closed to $(1,2)$, you can prove the limit is $0$ by translating the idea into $\epsilon-\delta$ language .